# Como muestro los gráficos en Notebook R

Tags: r

[image: introducir la descripción de la imageintroducir la descripción de la imagen aquín aquí]Hola, estoy realizando u informe en R con notebook de RStudio y cuando guardo el documento en PDF o html no me salen los grafico que si muestra en el notebook.

Alguien me podría ayudar, gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola eco0811! Puedes ofrecer información adicional sobre tu problema? Es importante saber: qué sistema operativo usas y que versión de R y cuál IDE usas. La función `R.Version()` ofrece información sobre el sistema versión de R. Es importante saber si aparece algún error o advertencia en la consola de R al momento de hacer 'knit' en tu documento, si tienes actualizados todos los paquetes y cuál es el encabezado YAML que usas. Qué pasa is usas "html_document" como output en el YAML?